# Batch normalization: converting tensorflow trained weights to pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, batch-normalization

I'm trying to convert an old tensorflow/keras network I have to pytorch and I'm confused as to the values I obtain of the batch_normalization (BN) weights. For example, the first BN layer of my pytorch network has two sets of elements (weight and bias) of shape [8]. In contrast, the same BN layer in tensorflow returns 4 sets of elements of shape [8].

Since I'm not planning on retraining the network once I've converted it to pytorch, I'd like to know which two sets of elements of the tensorflow BN layer are the corresponding for the pytorch BN layer.

Comment: Version of old tensorflow's code? What layers are used? Tensorflow probably has mean, variance (as parameters) and running_mean and running_variance, that's why there are four of them. PyTorch has the first two as weights as the second two as buffers.

Comment: I'm using Tensorflow 1.13.1, Keras 2.2.4 , and Pytorch 1.1.0. The original layer is from keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization().  and the pytorch layer is torch.nn.BatchNorm3d().

Comment: I found these two answers that suggest @SzymonMaszke's reply is correct, if anyone struggles with the same issue:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1523

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16149

Comment: Indeed, seems like that's exactly the case and the order is `[gamma, beta, running_mean, running_variance]`.